# Magento 1.9 : How to Get Customer Data using Rest API

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

We have tried to get Customer Data using the below URL. we have got the below error
URL: http://127.0.0.1/magento1940/api/rest/customer/:3

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpqLL.png

Comment: Please try with this link it will be help to you. https://devdocs.magento.com/swagger/index_23.html Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First, Your URL Request should be: GET `http://magentohost/api/rest/customers/2`

Finally, You are using REST API on Magento 1, you have to request a authenticate before call the API function.

- Preparing REST API for the Third-Party Application

[image: Preparing REST API for the Third-Party Application]

These steps are required for utilizing REST API resources:

- Set up permissions for REST resource operations from Magento Admin Panel.
- Configure the attributes for different users types in Magento Admin Panel. There are 3 different types of users in accessing the data: Admin, Customer, and Guest. Admin is the backend logged in user, Customer is the fronted logged in user, and Guest is a non-logged in fronted user.

PHP EXAMPLES:

```
<?php
/**
* Example of simple product POST using Admin account via Magento REST API. OAuth authorization is used
*/
$callbackUrl = "http://yourhost/oauth_admin.php";
$temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl = "http://magentohost/oauth/initiate?oauth_callback=" . urlencode($callbackUrl);
$adminAuthorizationUrl = 'http://magentohost/admin/oauth_authorize';
$accessTokenRequestUrl = 'http://magentohost/oauth/token';
$apiUrl = 'http://magentohost/api/rest';
$consumerKey = 'yourconsumerkey';
$consumerSecret = 'yourconsumersecret';

session_start();
if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && isset($_SESSION['state']) && $_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
    $_SESSION['state'] = 0;
}
try {
    $authType = ($_SESSION['state'] == 2) ? OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_AUTHORIZATION : OAUTH_AUTH_TYPE_URI;
    $oauthClient = new OAuth($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, OAUTH_SIG_METHOD_HMACSHA1, $authType);
    $oauthClient->enableDebug();

    if (!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && !$_SESSION['state']) {
        $requestToken = $oauthClient->getRequestToken($temporaryCredentialsRequestUrl);
        $_SESSION['secret'] = $requestToken['oauth_token_secret'];
        $_SESSION['state'] = 1;
        header('Location: ' . $adminAuthorizationUrl . '?oauth_token=' . $requestToken['oauth_token']);
        exit;
    } else if ($_SESSION['state'] == 1) {
        $oauthClient->setToken($_GET['oauth_token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
        $accessToken = $oauthClient->getAccessToken($accessTokenRequestUrl);
        $_SESSION['state'] = 2;
        $_SESSION['token'] = $accessToken['oauth_token'];
        $_SESSION['secret'] = $accessToken['oauth_token_secret'];
        header('Location: ' . $callbackUrl);
        exit;
    } else {
        $oauthClient->setToken($_SESSION['token'], $_SESSION['secret']);
        $resourceUrl = "$apiUrl/products";
        $productData = json_encode(array(
            'type_id'           => 'simple',
            'attribute_set_id'  => 4,
            'sku'               => 'simple' . uniqid(),
            'weight'            => 1,
            'status'            => 1,
            'visibility'        => 4,
            'name'              => 'Simple Product',
            'description'       => 'Simple Description',
            'short_description' => 'Simple Short Description',
            'price'             => 99.95,
            'tax_class_id'      => 0,
        ));
        $headers = array('Content-Type' => 'application/json');
        $oauthClient->fetch($resourceUrl, $productData, OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_POST, $headers);
        print_r($oauthClient->getLastResponseInfo());
    }
} catch (OAuthException $e) {
    print_r($e);
}
```

Check the detail document here: [Magento 1.x REST API](https://web.archive.org/web/20180406095041/http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/api/rest-api-index.html)